# NextJS how to render page as a string

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Upon calling a nextjs API, I need to render a page onto a string which can be manipulated. For instance, something like this:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
    const props = req.body.props()
    const html = next.render(<SomePage ...props>);
    doSomething(html);
    res.status(200);
}
```

I tried using `ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<SomePage>)` but that doesn't work as it only renders the components but not the whole page (e.g. doesn't add stylesheet, HTML tag etc).